# how to add constant force to a link

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am building a drone in gazebo. Wenn i use this->link->AddRelativeForce (), it seems like only an inpuls force is added to the link, but i need the force to be always applied on the link, how can i achive it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18163/how-to-add-constant-force-to-a-link/) by [gq38071112](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4278/gq38071112/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-12-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you want a continuous force, you'll need to re-apply it every iteration. You can do that connecting a callback to the `WorldUpdateBegin` event as done on [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=plugins_model&cat=write_plugin) tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2017-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gq38071112](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4278/gq38071112/) on 2017-12-26**:
Thanks for your answers. It works good and solves my problem